# unix command to grep for a particular word in a file

Tags: shell, unix

i have a file that has a pattern like this

```
String(`TYPE',`ABC')dnl 
String('TYPE',`BCD')dnl
```

and some other similar lines, so here i want this line  `String(`TYPE',`ABC')dnl` 
i am using this command

```
cat file | grep TYPE
```

which gives me the desired output but when i am using the same command inside one script it throws one error

```
`cat file | grep TYPE`
-bash: define(`TYPE',`ABC')dnl: command not found
```

what is that i need to modify in my command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the output from `grep` is being executed as a command because of the back-ticks.

First, you don't need the external program `cat`, `grep` takes the input filename as a parameter.  Second, it is wise to always enclose a pattern you are looking for in single quotes, to protect it from the shell.  In this case it is not strictly required, but it is a good habit to get into:

```
grep 'TYPE' file
```

Now, that command will write the result to standard-output (the screen).  If you want it stored in a variable then use the `$( )` notation rather than the deprecated back-ticks:

```
 var=$(grep 'TYPE' file)
```

now you can do what you like with `$var`.

You say you want the "word" `TYPE`.  What if you had this line in your file:

```
String(`UNTYPELESS',`ABC')dnl
```

Your search for `TYPE` would pick that up as well!  If you want to check for word boundaries you can use `egrep`:

```
egrep '\bTYPE\b' file
```

The `\b` indicates that a word-boundary (essentially any non-alpha, or beginning of text or end-of-text) must exist at that point in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need the `cat`
- You put shell cmd in back-ticks, the result of the cmd will be executed as new command, that's why you have the error msg
- If you just want to see the result, just `grep 'TYPE' file`
- If you want to assing the result to some var, `RESULT="$(grep 'TYPE' file)"`